# crudrepository save takes too long to update an entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I've got a controller that first selects all data with status = 'CREATED' transferType = 'SOME_TYPE' and DATE_TIME between x and y, and then put all the data in the List<TransferEntity>

then i am going through each element in the list and updating status to 'CHECKED'

```
if (listOfTransfers.isNotEmpty()){
    for(element in listOfTransfers){
        element.status = "CHECKED"
        repos.transfers.save(element)
    }
}
```

entity itself is pretty straight forward with no relations to other tables

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "TRANSFERS")
class TransferEntity(

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Identifier", nullable = false)
    var Identifier: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "TRANS_DATE_TIME")
    var transDateTime: LocalDateTime? = null,

    @Column(name = "TRANS_TYPE", nullable = true, length = 255)
    var transType: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    var status: String = ""
)
```

i tried to experiment with indexes (oracle)

```
`CREATE INDEX TRANS_INDEX_1 ON TRANSFERS(STATUS)`
`CREATE INDEX TRANS_INDEX_2 ON TRANSFERS(TRANS_DATE_TIME)`
`CREATE INDEX TRANS_INDEX_3 ON TRANSFERS(TRANS_TYPE)`
```

or created them as one index
`CREATE INDEX TRANS_INDEX_4 ON TRANSFERS(STATUS,TRANS_DATE_TIME,TRANS_TYPE)`

but it wasnt a big difference
**UPDATE**

- witn TRANS_INDEX_1 2 and 3 - 3192 elements were updateind in 5 minutes 30 sec
- with TRANS_INDEX_4 - 3192 elements were updated in 5 minutes 30 sec

maybe there are different approaches to mass update elements inside the list or perhaps indexes are completely wrong and i dont understand them as much as i want it to.

**UPDATE 2**
technically saveAll() method works much faster but still I think there should be a room for improvement

- saveAll() - 3192 elements were saved under 3minutes 21seconds
- save() 3192 elements were save under 5minutes 30 seconds

Comment: Write a query to update instead of select, iterate and update individual elements, save individual elements. Instead of the select you have make it an update, should fly in a couple of MS. Adding indexes might/will slow things down as those need to be updated for writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `save()` each time you update an element. 1000 elements will create 1000 query calls to the database, you repeat too many calls to your DB and that's why your function is slow.

Instead, you could use [saveAll](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#saveAll-java.lang.Iterable-)() after you updated all the elements

as suggested below, we also have to config the [batch_size](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-batch-inserts) properly to really do the trick

Indexes won't help in this situation since they benefit the select operation more than update or insert

Comment: `saveAll` won't help as that internally loops over the elements and calls `save`. Depending on wether this all runs in a TX or in no tx (single tx per element) it might generate 1000 queries or just 1 (if batching is properly configured).

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you, I've updated the answer to add some further reading about batch config. So, with proper config, let's say batch_size=1000 for example, we'll be able to reduce the query time right?

Comment: Sorry guys I updated time metrics and tried it with save and saveAll() methods both.

with save method 3192 elements in 5 minutes 30 sec.
with saveAll() method 3192 elements in 3 minutes 21 sec.

which is way faster but im afraid of comment by @M.Deinum. There is a difference but probabably there are more things to dig in.

Comment: Your question contains too little information (as we hinted how does this run transaction wise, you should also use proper batching, and probably just 1 single query for the update instead of select/iterate+update/save).

Comment: @M.Deinum i couldn't test if there were no batching at all but after adding spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 30 - speed increased even more.
3129 elements now updating under 1 minute 50 seconds. What botheres me is that when i change that parameter to 1000 speed stays the same. Regarding making select into update unfortunately i can't do that because there will be another logic with each element of list going thorugh another method. Just in case - all calculations of speed were done without that method

Comment: Again there is too little information, there is still no answer what you do transaction wise and apparently your question is overly simplyfied instead of actual code.

Comment: If your ORM engine is hibernate, you can monitor the SQL request (adding `show_sql=true` in the hibernate parameters). You will make sure that you have only 3192 update statements and that your are not polluted with other requests cast by hibernate behind your back.

Answer (score 1):

Since you set the same value to all the elements of your list, you can make a batch update query :

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("update TransferEntity t set t.status = :value where t in (:list)");
q.setParameter("value", "CHECKED");
q.setParamter("list", listOfTransfers);
q.execute();
```

If you use ORACLE as backend be aware that `in` clause is limited to 1000 elements. Therefore you might have to split your list in buckets of 1000 elements and loop on this query for each bucket.